# Rich and widely used Ruby GUI framework for Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, user-interface, frameworks

I read about wxRuby and Shoes but never used them. I want to learn ruby by developing a real-world serious Windows application. Among the available frameworks, which one is widely used and acceptable, rich in libraries and comes bundled with .exe builder?

Comment: You mean GUI. But most *serious* applications don't have it and don't need neither wxRuby nor Shoes. Anyway, `Qt` for Ruby has some toolkits for easy GUI projecting.

Comment: @Nakilon: Yes I mean GUI. I just found another, it is FxRuby. How about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't a great deal of sensible choices for client/desktop applications in Ruby right now, however I believe one of your best options is to take advantage of mature JVM libraries via JRuby.

The [Redcar text editor](http://redcareditor.com/) is written in Ruby and runs on the JVM, and you can view the source on Github here https://github.com/danlucraft/redcar

There is also a development company called [Atomic Object](http://www.atomicobject.com/) that made a neat Ruby desktop app using JRuby with a fairly sophisticated GUI and you can view that [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2009/01/30/ruby-for-desktop-applications-yes-we-can).

I've been thinking about the exact same problem as you and keeping and eye on my the options, these last few months :-)

I've also been using JRuby on the server-side and it's solid and reliable.

Finally, if it's Windows-only as you say, then you could consider using a .NET GUI Framework like [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) and build it using IronRuby, however IronRuby is not yet as mature as JRuby, so you could be exposing yourself to some risk there in terms of compatibility, bugs and performance (and for the record, I like IronRuby!).

However, the potential issues of using IronRuby might be balanced out by the gains you'd make using a GUI framework that's designed and optimised for Windows and is nicer than Swing. WPF is about as rich as it gets for GUI frameworks on Windows.

Comment: @Nakilon I believe you, but it's only fair to get some balanced data here, so I'm going to counter your observation with: I've got a 2009 MacBook Pro and it launches the current version of Redcar in 12 seconds. Not 'OMG awesome', but acceptable. I'm not claiming that you won't need more resources - you are bound to need more RAM than a native app, for example, but it's perfectly usable. There is also more to consider than startup times - once the app is up and running, the mature JVM garbage collector is quite a bonus for Ruby applications. Don't now how well Redcar runs on Windows, though.

Comment: 12 seconds are too much for SciTE/Textmate-like editor. Even many times more powerfull IDEs like Visual Studio works much easier. I don't like to buy new RAM only for software, which is more like Notepad, than VS.

Comment: Oh guys, if RAM is the factor go for plain old C GUI programming. Today (also 2010) even Android devs are thinking less about memory. Start time is a matter of optimization - vm params - unless you need start-in-1sec image viewer or whatever. Joining mature (Java/JVM) and flexible (Ruby) technology gives you enormous possibilities, not mentioning portability, books, huge community and staff availability - serious software it is not only a choice of technology.

Answer (score 0):

There are bindings for Qt on [GitHub](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings). I believe it's a fork from the Korundum bindings from KDE. However, I haven't tried it on Windows yet.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using RubyTk. Tk is a toolkit that works with many languages including ruby. For more information see [tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com)

disclaimer: I have no idea how widely used it is, though Tk in general is used in many places for both commercial, internal and open source projects.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/GUI_Toolkit_Modules will help

In terms of popularity, in 2008 shooes was most popular, but that has probably dropped.

http://www.pressure.to/ruby_gui_survey/

Answer (score 0):

Since [RubyInstaller project](http://rubyinstaller.org/)  bundles now [complete modern Tk distribution and bindings](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2126395) eliminating Windows installation woes- Tk seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

With RubyGems I believe it is now possible to install [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) for this. So says [this](http://rubygems.org/gems/gtk2) in Gems. This is a widely used framework, both in open source and industry. It is used in [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and, I think, presents a good windows system that is close to native and easily useable.